# Birchas Ha'Gomel for ocean fishing

Tags: halacha, travel, hagomel

Someone went fishing in the ocean on a eight hour outing off the Jersey shore [they go out a few miles], and wanted to know if he needs to make a birchas hagomel like all those that travel at sea. See [OC 219:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.219.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

In Su"T Betzel HaChochma [6/115] he writes that fishermen need to make this bracha for an excursion a few "mil" out. I have never seen or heard about anyone that made this bracha for this type of  trip.

Does anyone know of any other source, or "minhag" regarding a bracha in this type of situation?

Comment: Sefardim are more strict with regards to making the bracha

Comment: @sam you might want to reword that. I, for one, have no idea whether you meant they say it more often or less.

Comment: Meant they say it more often ,meaning going from city to city is even a reason to say it if it is a parsah or more.

Comment: @sam are you speaking of Hagomel or Tfilat Haderech?

Comment: Hagomel,they determine it based off distance not so much danger,not every pose holds lmaaseh,but I do know of a few who do

Comment: @sam thanks (by the way if you want the system to ping me when answering, you need to add "ampersand-mbloch" otherwise it only pings the person asking the question, this is not necessary only if there is only one comment or comments by only one person).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dinonline answers your question [here](http://dinonline.org/2015/08/10/gratitude-for-surviving-danger-when-to-say-birkas-ha-gomel/) and writes Birkat ha-gomel should not be recited for a short fishing trip

> Shut Kinyan Torah (Vol. 1, no. 16, sec. 3) writes that somebody who
>   sails across the Channel between England and France does not recite
>   the blessing because the journey is short: Just as those who cross the
>   desert only recite ha-gomel after a lengthy journey, so in sailing on
>   the sea ha-gomel is only recited after a trip of significant length.
>
> **The same principle applies to other short sailing trips, such as a
>   short cruise or a fishing trip, after which ha-gomel is not recited.**
>   Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach (Halichos Shlomo Chap. 23, Devar Halachah
>   5) writes that somebody who sails on the Kinneret, or near the shore,
>   should not recite ha-gomel, because in case of trouble help can be
>   given from the shore.

This might be a *machloket* Ashkenazim-Sefaradim though as R Yirmiyohu Kaganoff notes [here](https://rabbikaganoff.com/what-warrants-birchas-hagomeil/)

> The Biur Halacha discusses whether one travelling a short trip by
>   river on a raft should recite birchas hagomeil. He says that it
>   depends on the above-mentioned dispute between Ashkenazim and Sefardim
>   whether one recites birchas hagomeil for a short intercity land trip.
>   **According to minhag Ashkenaz, that one does not recite birchas
>   hagomeil for a short trip, one should not recite birchas hagomeil for
>   a trip by raft; whereas, according to minhag Sefard, which recites
>   birchas hagomeil even for a short intercity trip, one should recite
>   birchas hagomeil for a short river trip.**

(by *minhag Sefard* I believe he means Sefaradi/Edot HaMizrach)