# Birkat Hagomel for Eurostar?

Tags: modern-times, hagomel

Does one say birkat hagomel after taking the Eurostar (eg from London to Paris)?

I know we say it after: being freed from jail, being healed from sickness, *travelling at sea*, or travelling in the desert.

1) The train travels through the English Channel. I'm assuming this would still be called a "sea" by halakha.

2) We are travelling by train, whereas the bracha was probably intended for boats. I know (most agree) that aeroplanes require gomel, so I'd assume it's the same for a train.

3) I'm also wondering if there's something to be said about the length of the journey? It's quite short and a lot of it isn't even underwater.

Comment: Could you explain more what the Eurostar is?

Comment: I have not seen that most agree airplanes require gamel rather than a modified tefila haderech...this is entirely parnthetical to the main thrust of your question but a source would be usefuk

Comment: Considering the large number of people who have successfully swum across the Channel, I'm not sure it should qualify as a *yam* (sea) rather than, say, very wide "river".

Comment: @robev the Eurostar is an express train going from Paris to London under the Channel (the part of the sea between France and UK). It goes through a specially constructed tunnel there and is a very popular option to travel between these two cities

Comment: @Loewian - "very wide river"?!?  I wonder if any of the guys crossing it on D-Day thought it was one of those..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contemporary Poskim -  [שבט הלוי](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1419&st=&pgnum=54)  and [להורות נתן](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14691&st=&pgnum=25)  among others - are of the opinion that one does not say the bracha after traveling in a tunnel under water, since there is no constant danger. They were discussing travel by car etc., the same reason should apply by a train.

You might want to see the answer given by mbloch here [Birchas Ha'Gomel for ocean fishing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/106131/birchas-hagomel-for-ocean-fishing) for a second reason.

Comment: My cousin ע"ה was one of Mitterrand's liaisons for the Chunnel project in the 1980s and his experiences with it would probably contravene the idea that there's a lack of constant danger